# Получить название COM порта по GUID и описанию устройства

Tags: c++, winapi, com-port

Хочу автоматизировать подключение к виртуальному com-порту своего устройства. Чтобы каждый раз не залезать и не смотреть какой com-port создался.

Я попробовал решить это вот так:

```
        //Тут получаю GUID всех подключенных устройств класса Ports
        if (SetupDiClassGuidsFromNameA("Ports", guidlist, 256, &size)) {
        //По совету MSDN создаю пустой info list
        HDEVINFO info = SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(guidlist, NULL);
        //А дальше лыжи не едут :(
        if (SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoA(info, "USB\\VID_0483&PID_5740", guidlist, NULL, NULL, DICD_GENERATE_ID, NULL)) {
            const ULONG port_num_count = 256;
            ULONG find_port_num = 0;
            ULONG port_numbers[port_num_count];
            //Это старый подход показывает все активные com-порты и можно выбрать из списка
            GetCommPorts(port_numbers, port_num_count, &find_port_num);
            for (auto it : port_numbers) {
                if (it == 3) break;
            }
        }
        else {
            //выдает ошибку 3758096901 или 0xE0000205 но я ее не нашел в winerror
            std::cout <<  GetLastError();
        }
    }
```

В реестре вся инфа красиво лежит(см. фото). Нужно получить эту инфу, а дальше я уже сделаю. В идеале, чтобы это не требовало админских прав и работала на разных версиях windows. Подскажите что я делаю не правильно или подскажите куда копать. Просто я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в winapi, я больше по микроконтроллерам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогли найти решение испульзуя WMI [Win32_SerialPort class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-serialport), [Win32_PnPEntity class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity), [Example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer). Можно проверить запросы к WMI через Wmic или через [WMI Code Creator v1.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8572)

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
    );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
        NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
        NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
        0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
        NULL,                    // Security flags.
        0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
        0,                       // Context object 
        &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort WHERE Description = 'STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port'"),//!!!REQUEST!!!
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"DeviceID", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);//!!!!Parsing result
        wcout << " COM PORT NAME : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.

}
```